# devise-async and delayed_job not sending emails with delayed_job (rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, devise, actionmailer, devise-async

I'm trying to send devise mails (default devise mailer) asynchronously with `devise_async`. However, the mailer does not send them; they only get saved in the delayed_jobs table. I followed the `devise-async` documentation step by step:

**devise_async.rb:**

```
Devise::Async.setup do |config|
  config.enabled = true
  config.backend = :delayed_job
end
```

**application.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

Also added `:async` to **user.rb**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Set Devise::Async.queue = :default. [stackoverflow][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933788/using-devise-async-to-send-out-emails-does-not-work-rails-sidekiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now you have to actually *run* these jobs :)

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

Comment: Will all background jobs in the future start this way, always? It's my first time using background jobs, so any explanation is welcome :)

Comment: This command will actually start background worker(s), which will stay in memory forever (unless something kills them). How do you manage your workers in your production environment is whole other story.